# Why is "reconstruct" used instead of "reconstructs" or "reconstructed" in this sentence?

Tags: verb-agreement, conjugation

Why did the author write "reconstruct" instead of writing "reconstructs/reconstructed"? Is it an exception to normal subject-verb agreement rules?

> It may be argued that the creation-template offered in the phrases of the
>   institutional theory in truth rationally **reconstruct** the facts of creativity, imposing order on very messy diversity, and that will perhaps be convincing to those committed to the return to theory, committed to the search for essence.

Source:  "The Institutional Theory of Art: Theory and Antitheory", by Garry L. Hagberg, in *[A Companion to Art Theory](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/A+Companion+to+Art+Theory-p-9780470998427),* edited by Paul Smith and Carolyn Wilde, p. 501

Comment: The subject of the sentence is _creation-template_, which requires a singular verb. The author was likely confused by the intervening _phrases_ and an editor didn't catch it.

Comment: Because the passage is so strange, any editor would have had to use all his faculties just to stay awake reading it… and using up all his faculties would leave nothing to correct it!

Test such things by dumping the irrelevancies, as in "… the creation-template… reconstruct/reconstructs/reconstructed”?